# HTML & CSS: My form causes all other elements in it's parent container to become mis-aligned

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/1xqfsbLr/

Here's a site that i'm working on. Unfortunately, my form causes all the other elements in the nav bar to become mis-aligned vertically (shifting down by 5 pixels). is there any way I can fix this, while keeping the layout of the form (the position of the input box inside the form) the same? I would like to keep the form in the below nav bar if possible. Thanks.

```
<nav>
<form action="search.php" method="post" id="Search">
<input type="search" class="searchbox" name="query" placeholder="Enter Your Search Term Here"/>
</form>
<div class="nav_element" id="BluRays">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="nav_element" id="DVDs">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="nav_element" id="Login">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="nav_element" id="Register">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="nav_element" id="My_Account">&nbsp;</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What output you want? like https://jsfiddle.net/1xqfsbLr/1/?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you are using `display: inline-block;` on your form element?

Comment: @Ketan Yeah, that's the one :) What did you change?

Comment: @JohnBergqvist you can check it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you just need to add `vertical-align:top` to your `.nav_element` because `inline-block` by default is set to `baseline`

here is a snippet:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
}
.site_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1380px;
  background-color: blue;
}
nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 1180px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-image: url(logo.png);
}
.nav_element {
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.nav_element:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#Search {
  width: 280px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.searchbox {
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #c3c8c8;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
#DVDs {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/DVD.png");
}
#DVDs:hover {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/DVD_highlight.png");
}
#BluRays {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/BluRays.png");
}
#BluRays:hover {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/BluRays_highlight.png");
}
#BluRays {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/BluRay.png");
}
#BluRays:hover {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/BluRay_highlight.png");
}
#Login {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/Login.png");
}
#Login:hover {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/Login_highlight.png");
}
#Logout {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/Logout.png");
}
#Logout:hover {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/Logout_highlight.png");
}
#Register {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/Register.png");
}
#Register:hover {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/Register_highlight.png");
}
#My_Account {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/Account.png");
}
#My_Account:hover {
  background-image: url("/img/buttons/Account_highlight.png");
}
aside {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #dfe0e1;
}
.basket {
  position: absolute;
  height: 800px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="site_wrapper">
    <div class="logo">&nbsp;</div>

    <nav>
      <form action="search.php" method="post" id="Search">
        <input type="search" class="searchbox" name="query" placeholder="Enter Your Search Term Here" />
      </form>
      <div class="nav_element" id="BluRays">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="nav_element" id="DVDs">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="nav_element" id="Login">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="nav_element" id="Register">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="nav_element" id="My_Account">&nbsp;</div>
    </nav>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That fixes the alignment, but weirdly the whole position of the nav element changes to sometimes be at the very top of the page (next to the logo element - which is how i want it), but other times to be below the logo element. But this happens randomly, when i refresh the page. Here's a screenshot of the two http://i.imgur.com/nD25tGO.png

Comment: OK, setting nav to top:0 fixes that problem :)

Comment: or you could put `vertical-align:top`in every `display:inline-block`, that would fix too.

Answer (score 0):

Just simple give `vertical-align: top;` to `.nav_element` will solved your issue.

```
.nav_element {
text-align:center;
height:40px;
width:140px;
background-color:white;
display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1xqfsbLr/1/)